# Tell WPF to evaluate bindings

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, binding

Say I have a command's execute method that looks like this:

```
    private void Execute()
    {
        // Bound to a wait indicator in the UI
        Searching = true;

        // Do some long running process
        Thread.Sleep(2000);

        Searching = false;
    }
```

When Searching is set to True, the UI element that it is bound to will not update (even though Searching sends the OnPropertyChanged call).

However, once the Thread.Sleep finishes, then the UI then processes my change and shows the wait indicator that Searching is bound to.

Now, I know the conventional wisdom is to make the call to the long running process (Thread.Sleep) be async.

But suppose I am not using the Async libraries, **is there a way to instruct WPF to perform the binding on Searching right now?**

Something like this:

```
    private void Execute()
    {
        // Bound to a wait indicator in the UI
        Searching = true;

        // MADE UP CODE
        Binding.UpdateBindingNow("Searching");
        // END MADE UP CODE


        // Do some long running process
        Thread.Sleep(2000);

        Searching = false;
    }
```

UPDATE: What I have tried:

- Using Dispatcher to try sending the command to the UI Separately.
- I also tried the Dispatcher with a high priority.

Comment: Async is the way to go. If you intend to use something like the winforms' `Application.DoEvents()` you're in the wrong track. By the way, I don't know what you mean by `But suppose I am not using the Async libraries`. Async support is built-into the .Net Framework since 1.1

Answer (score 5):

You need to push your work into a background thread.  The bindings won't update until the UI thread can process messages, which won't happen until your operation completes.

Async is one approach, but a more classic approach would be to just use [`BackgroundWorker`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) to do this, which is supported in all versions of WPF.

If you're using .NET 4, you could do this via the TPL, as well:

```
private void Execute()
{
    // Bound to a wait indicator in the UI
    Searching = true;

    Task.Factory.StartNew( () => { 
        // Do long running work... 
    }).ContinueWith(t =>
    {
        // You can do work here, including touching UI controls/collections/etc
        Searching = false;
    }, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I agree with others that moving the long-running process to a background/asynch operation is the best way to go.  Both because your UI doesn't freeze for the user and also because whatever you do (refresh your binding, whatever) won't actually be reflected in the UI while the long-running process is working because the UI thread will be blocked.

That said, your question is can you force the binding to evaluate/refresh from code, and the answer is yes.  You accomplish this by calling `UpdateTarget` on the `BindingExpression` like this:

```
labelTextBlock.GetBindingExpression(TextBlock.TextProperty).UpdateTarget();
```

There is also an `UpdateSource` method on the `BindingExpression` that can be used in much the same way, only impacting the source rather than target.

Again, if your UI thread is blocked, it may not accomplish what you're hoping for, but this is how you would force the binding to re-evaluate.